# Algorithms for mapping data in data mining

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-mining, text-mining

I need to scrape some webpages and extract content from them. I'm planning to select some specific keywords and map the data that has some relationship b/w them. But I have no Idea, how I could do that. Could anyone suggest me some algorithms for doing it?.

For example I need to download some webpages about apples and map the relevant data about apples to it and store in database so that, if someone needs specific information about it, I could provide it fastly and accurately.

Also it would be helpful pointing out helpful libraries too. I'm planning to do it in python.

Comment: There is 1 famous main algorithm for that. I suggest you to search on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/), [Pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern) or [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) modules.

As a start "[Programming collective intelligence: building smart web 2. 0 applications](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321)" by Toby Segaran is a good book to read.

Answer (score 1):

You could try algorithms based on *term frequency–inverse document frequency* [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf), in Java I would recommend [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) ... well actually you could use Solr and access it with python [see here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPython)